# AngularJS filter array in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter an array in a controller but it returns nothing.

This is my controller:

```html
.controller('cardsCtrl', function($scope, $sce, LearnCard, Category, $ionicModal, $stateParams, $filter) {

  console.log("stateParam: " + $stateParams.catId);

  // Get all LearnCards
  $scope.learnCardsAll = LearnCard.query();
  console.log("Before filtering");
  console.log($scope.learnCardsAll); // is populated

  $scope.learnCards = $filter('filter')($scope.learnCardsAll, { category: 1 });
```

learnCardsAll is populated as it should.

This is the structure of the elements:
[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UxWw.png)

Maybe someone could help me?

Comment: Have you tried using [lodash's _.filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) method?

Comment: If you can see that `$scope.learnCardsAll` is populated, then `$scope.learnCards = _.filter($scope.learnCardsAll, {category: 1});` should work;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.query` method is async and takes a callback.

Try to do your filtering inside of it.

```
LearnCard.query(function(cards) {
  $scope.learnCards = $filter('filter')(cards, { category: 1 });
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Thank you! That solves my problem... somehow. The view takes the filtered list. There is so much new stuff to read through and input so I did not think of that.